# Spring boot starter parent version update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

my current spring boot project has spring boot starter parent dependency pom file with version as 1.5.release. Is it possible to upgrade to version 2.0. If so, how can we achieve this?

Comment: Take a look [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)

Answer (score 0):

Just write `<version>2.0.0</version>` below the artifactId tag for the dependency.